# react native Scroll View doesn't scroll from inside text input

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I added multi Text input inside a scroll view. the problem is when I want to scroll down from inside of a text input, I put my finger inside a text input and scroll down but it doesn't scroll down the page, is there a way to fix this?
here is a sample code:

```
export default class ScrollViewWithTextInput extends React.Component {
render() {
    <ScrollView>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        /><TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        /><TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        /><TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        /><TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={'توضیحات'}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
    </ScrollView>
}}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
Container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 8
},
input: {
    width: 350,
    height: 100,
    margin: 5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
    textAlign: 'right'
}})
```

Comment: we should probably see your code

Comment: I added a Sample code, and the strange thing is , when I set textAlign to 'left' things work, it doesn't work on 'center' or 'right'

Comment: 1. Probably when the text is aligned to the right or center, the whole input is being considered as "filled with text", but with default "left" position, a TextInput assumes the text to be only where we see it.
2. I checked your app on iOS, the scrolling worked.
3. You are missing return statement in your code.

Comment: the problem is present in android, if I remove textAlign and placeholder, it works, if placeholder exist, I should scroll two times and then it works, I think it's a very annoying bug. btw, thank you for your help

Comment: and another thing, no matter if textAlign is set or not, when I use a rtl language, the problem exist

Comment: if you think it's a bug, you could report it to the react-native team on their GitHub page in the issues section so that  the problem gets fixed

Answer (score 5):

For some reason setting `multiline={true}` to the TextInput worked for me.

Not exactly sure why. Stranger still, it will not work if you also have `keyboardType='numeric'`.

Answer (score 2):

Use each input as a component.  try something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.input.focus()} >
    <View pointerEvents="none" >
        <TextInput ref = {(input) => this.input = input} />
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

setting

`<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`

in combination with the textInout component below (custom component that i created for text inputs to solve this issue) solved my problem:

```
<TouchableOpacity
         activeOpacity={1}
         onPress={()=>this.input.focus()}>
         <View
               pointerEvents="none">
               <TextInput
                  ref = {(input) => this.input = input}
               />
         </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

**Update**

a better expression might be:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._keyboardDidHide = this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this)
    this.onSubmitEditing = this.onSubmitEditing.bind(this)
}

componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide)
};
componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}
_keyboardDidHide(){
    this.input.blur()
}
```

and then the expression above for the TextInput component. because in the previous expression when you press back and the keyboard hides, and you tap on that input again, the keyboard doesn't open, because that input is already focused. so you need to blur and then focus again.

this is my idea, maybe you might perform this in a more creative way :)

btw don't forget to import Keyboard from 'react-native' if you use my expression.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how, but in my case it helped to replace TextInput with styledComonent, and using it as TextInput

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

export const StyledInput = styled.TextInput``
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to adjust the `height` of the input.
I don't really understand why but it solved my problem.