# ScrollView only scrolls when placing finger inside of an input

Tags: react-native, scrollview, native-base

I'm having a weird behavior here and I can't figure out what's going on. I have a `ScrolView` with a form and some inputs and labels inside and it seems to only want to scroll when you place your finger (or cursor in the demo) over an input or a switch and it doesn't scroll when placing your finger anywhere else in the `ScrollView`

I put together an Expo Snack to show the code and if you run in the emulator and attempt to scroll the `ScrollView` by placing the cursor over one of the labels or on the edges of the `ScrollView` it won't scroll but if you place the cursor over an input or a switch it scrolls just fine

https://snack.expo.io/@jordanr/weird-scrollview-bahavior

Comment: Your `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` wrapping the whole app seems to interfere with the scroll. It works fine when I remove it

Comment: just solved issue in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54968807/8898138) hope it solves your problem too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because **Touchable effects** in your `TouchableWithoutFeedback` are blocking the effects of `ScrollView`, therefore you need to reset your responder by wrapping the `Content` inside the `View`

```
<Content>
   <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}>
   //... Rest of the code
   </View>
</Content>
```

Also don't use `ScrollView` since **NativeBase** uses `KeyboardAwareScrollView` from the package `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` in the `<Content/>`